# Edge optimised API Gateway and lambda deployed in a single location

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway

I'm located in the EU, and I have an edge-optimized REST API Gateway deployed in `us-east-1`. My API Gateway proxies all requests to a lambda function, again located in `us-east-1`.

So I'm assuming whenever I send a request to this API Gateway, I'm being served from a nearby location (such as `eu-central-1`, etc.) instead of `us-east-1` because of Edge functionality.

Actually, I also tested this behavior by changing the API type to "regional" and and then back to "edge-optimized", and observed the following results:

- Regional:

```
  DNS Lookup   TCP Connection   TLS Handshake   Server Processing   Content Transfer
[     6ms    |      113ms     |     247ms     |       141ms       |        1ms       ]
             |                |               |                   |                  |
    namelookup:6ms            |               |                   |                  |
                        connect:119ms         |                   |                  |
                                    pretransfer:366ms             |                  |
                                                      starttransfer:507ms            |
                                                                                 total:508ms
```

As you can see, TCP connection and TLS handshake are taking longer, as expected, when I'm using the Regional type because of the round trips between the EU and US.

- Edge-Optimized:

When using the Edge-Optimized type, I noticed that server processing was taking too long, but TCP and TLS parts are fast:

```
  DNS Lookup   TCP Connection   TLS Handshake   Server Processing   Content Transfer
[     5ms    |       7ms      |     17ms      |       351ms       |        1ms       ]
             |                |               |                   |                  |
    namelookup:5ms            |               |                   |                  |
                        connect:12ms          |                   |                  |
                                    pretransfer:29ms              |                  |
                                                      starttransfer:380ms            |
                                                                                 total:381ms
```

According to my theory, my requests go to a nearby API Gateway edge such as `eu-central-1`, but the latency between this edge node and the lambda function located in `us-east-1` is high. Therefore server processing part is taking too long.

- How do edge-optimized API Gateways deal with lambdas only deployed in a single location?
- What's the best practice to speed up this endpoint?

Thanks!